# Fire off JavaScript function when textbox is populated and focus is still set in jQuery?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

How do I execute an JavaScript function right when an ASP.NET text box control is populated and focus is still set?  The `onChange` event will not work because I need to programmatically move focus to the next form element after the JavaScript function has executed.

Is is very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002209/execute-a-javascript-function-when-textbox-is-populated-in-jquery).  The marked answer is correct for the context on the question, but after some more testing it did not exactly solve my current issue.

Pseudo code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function MyFunction() {
        //execute this function when MyTxtBox is populated and focus is still set
        //once core function is completed, move focus to MyTxtBox1
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .USBBox
     {
         position: absolute;
         left: -999em; 
         overflow: hidden;
     } 
</style>   
<asp:TextBox id="MyTxtBox" runat="server" CssClass="USBBox" />
<asp:TextBox id="MyTxtBox1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Could you explain how the linked question does not meet your requirements? Technically, however this is a duplicate!

Comment: @James - The user is using an USB credit card swiper and I had to press the tab key to move to the next form element in order to execute the JS function.  I need to eliminate the tab press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#MyTxtBox').keyup(MyFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `onkeypress` or `onkeyup` to accomplish this.